# When user logout from page ... if user click browser back button ,which will redirect to previous URL and display HTML page for few seconds

Tags: javascript, angularjs, back-button

I am working in angular js, When a user logged out from the browser and click browser back button (or) user Bookmark URL and load after logout.
 will load the controller page and check session exists, If not redirect to login page.
which will take 5 seconds time and display UI of the previous page after logout?

Please give me a solution How to solve this issue

sorry if I ask a basic question, please give me a clear explanation friends

I didn't have any friends working on angular js

Comment: Do you want to prevent the user to load content if he is logged out?

Comment: Yes sir, I want to prevent loading after logged out

Comment: Are you using Angular 1.x or 2 ?

Comment: Angular 1.x sir.......

Comment: Please use [tag:angularjs] tag for questions about angular v1.x, and [tag:angular] for version 2.x+ (Already re-tagged this question). Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `authGuard` service provided by angular2. 
where you can control user to load particular template on the basis of condition which is based on your condition i.e login/logout in your case

you can use their default methods like `canActivate` and `canActivateChild`

see here

- http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/18/guards-in-angular-2.html
- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

> Because you have to check your logic/condition on routing or we can say before page load so you have to use Guard of angular2 in routing